# Movement in unity; Non diagonal, zelda like

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I'm testing around with Unity and Visual Studio, and as a starter project I'm working to replicate Zelda (NES) and I'm starting with movement.

So far, with much jank, I've figured out how to prevent diagonal movement, but I'm having trouble figuring out the next part. In the game, if favors vertical movement when there are 2 inputs, but if you hit a wall, it lets you move horizontally until nothing is blocking your vertical movement.

I do not know enough to even think about how to do this. Anyone have an idea that can set me the right direction? Or perhaps just a better way of doing it? I'm still learning C#

```
public float MoveSpeed;
public Rigidbody2D rb;
Vector2 movement;

void Update() {
    MovementInput();
}

private void FixedUpdate() {
    rb.velocity = movement * MoveSpeed;
}

void MovementInput() {
    float mx = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float my = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    //This makes diagonal impossible, favoring vertical.
    if (my != 0) {
        mx = 0;
    }

    movement = new Vector2(mx, my).normalized;
}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the Axis is a value between -1 and 1. It might be worth considering taking both the X and Y values, use [Mathf.Abs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Abs.html), and then see which is bigger to see which should be getting applied instead. Would need to account for when they are equal, but should be a much smaller movement bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to compare the horizontal and the vertical axis absolute value. The highest would gives you the good direction.

```
if (Math.Abs(my) > Math.Abs(mx)) {
    // up or down
} else {
    // left or right
}
```